# Example of a symbolic or a discrete dynamical system where $NW(f) \not\subset \overline{R(f)}$?

Tags: dynamical-systems

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011745/example-of-dynamical-system-where-nwf-not-subset-overlinerf) there is an example of a continuous dynamical system with $NW(f) \not\subset \overline{R(f)}$. The definitions I am working with are exactly same as that question. I want to find a symbolic or a discrete dynamical system with the mentioned property. I would really appreciate a not-so-involved example, so that I can gain an intuition to distinguish non-wandering points from points in the closure of the set of all recurrent points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One example is the orbit closure of ${}^\infty 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 \cdots 1 0^n 1 0^{n+1} 1 \cdots$ with respect to the shift map. The left tail is just repeating 0s, and on the right are 1s with increasing gaps. The only recurrent point is the all-0 configuration, but ${}^\infty 0 1 0^\infty$ is nonwandering.

Comment: There is no other element in the orbit closure than $\infty 010\infty$ and all-$0$ which is not in the orbit, right? Btw, thank you very much, I think this example fits perfectly to what I was searching.

Comment: @テレビ スクリーン Correct. The shift space contains the point I defined, the point ${}^\infty 010^\infty$, the all-0 point and their shifts, nothing more.