# Homoclinic, heteroclinic orbits and nonwandering points

Tags: differential-topology, dynamical-systems, vector-fields, bifurcation

I have a relatively well behaved vector field and I can prove that all the nonwandering points along the flow are equilibria. Is this enough to disprove that there is no homoclinic and heteroclinic cycles? In this [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2011745/example-of-dynamical-system-where-nwf-not-subset-overlinerf), in the accepted answer it is claimed that "*single homoclinic loop consists of non-wandering points*". I am also looking for a proof/reference for this claim that according to the user is based on the $\lambda$-lemma. Therefore, if (in my case) all nonwandering points are equilibria, does this disprove the existence of homoclinic orbits? Is it also true for etheroclinic loops (heteroclinic orbits connecting multiple equilibria in a loop).

Some analysis could be probably found [here](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-1042-9) and it seems like the fact it's not true in general?. Currently reading.

Comment: It is **hetero**clinic, not etheroclinic

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the repeated typo D: